# How to Navigate from Drawer menu Header item to Particular Fragment

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I am using Navigation Component to navigate

[This is the Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iKzo.jpg)

Main Activity code here :

```
lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
lateinit var navController: NavController

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    Utils.setStatusBarGradiant(this)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    supportActionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_theme))


   // bottom navigation
   navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
   bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)

   //Navigation UP Button
   appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, drawer_Layout)
   //create arrow button
   NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawer_Layout)

  //Drawer Navigation
  NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(nav_view, navController)
}

 // click on arrow button ( back to home fragment function)
  override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
  return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

}

Main Activity XML file here :

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout

```
android:id="@+id/drawer_Layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"/>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/newgradient"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/newgradient"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_view" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    android:background="@color/drawerblack"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/yt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

[This is the Navigation Drawer Menu Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KwTf.jpg)

My Question is : When I Click on Orders in Navigation Drawer Menu , I want to go to Order Fragment which is inside Main Activity